# Get all exceptions that are catched by IMethod

Tags: java, exception, plugins, methods

I´m currently developing an Eclipse plugin for showing a graph with expeption flows(which method throws the Exception and which method catches the exception).

Question is: I have an IMethod instance and I want to get all the exceptions it catches(not throws). I can do that recently but only analyzing the source code of the IMethod as a string and finding if it has the clause "catch(" or "catch (" and picking up the exception names.

Is there a better way to do this? To find which Exception types a method catches?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ASTParser` to parse a `ICompilationUnit`. The parse result can then be traversed using an `ASTVisitor`:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
parser.setSource(compilationUnit);

ASTNode node = ASTparser.createAST(progressMonitor);
node.accept(visitor);
```

Subclass `ASTVisitor` to get notified when certain nodes are visited/left:

```
public class MyVisitor extends ASTVisitor {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
        // method begin
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean visit(CatchClause catchClause) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void endVisit(MethodDeclaration node) {
        // method end
    }
}
```

See also:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html#ast_example
- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly you want something like this:

```
    try {
         //do sth
    } catch(Exception e) { 
       Class c = e.getClass();
       String exceptionType = c.getName(); 
    }
```